# Does spending/losing reputation via setting bounties remove privileges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, privileges

Like for example, if I spent all my reputation giving out bounties next month, would I lose my editing, voting and commenting privileges?

Comment: I lost my rights to upvote, comment and (almost also) breathe on Hinduism SE when I gave away my whole association bonus of 100 rep in a bounty on my friend's question :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [faq](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) says you do:

> If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any
>   privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.

Comment: Thanks man, I should have read the FAQs first but I didn't even know they existed!

Comment: @JoelDamien Honestly, I doubt a lot of people read FAQs.